# "No application Data found" in Ubuntu software on 16.10

Tags: software-center

`No application Data found` is displayed on the starting screen of the Ubuntu software in Ubuntu 16.10. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: In `terminal`, type `sudo apt-get update` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: already tried...... but did not work.... Still showing the same message

Answer (score 0):

From the **Updates** tab, click on the refresh icon in the very top left and wait for it to refresh and it should populate the data.